# find position of signature in an image with ocr

Tags: c#, .net, ocr

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7xs9.png)

Currently i am using tessert ocr to recognize the coordinates of the signature in the image using below snippet but it gets stucks at the third line ocr.setvariable without any error

I have tried below snippet using tessert but with no success getting stuck.
Please suggest if there is any other ocr tool to recognize signature coordinate  in an image

actual output : 145*145 which are x-axis and y-axis.
Ready to use any other tool which is open source

```
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\shwetac\Downloads\Docs\abcd.bmp");
tessnet2.Tesseract ocr = new tessnet2.Tesseract();
ocr.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789"); // If digit only
ocr.Init(@"D:\temp", "fra", false); // To use correct tessdata
List<tessnet2.Word> result = ocr.DoOCR(image, Rectangle.Empty);
foreach (tessnet2.Word word in result)
         Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", word.Confidence, word.Text);
```

http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/

Comment: Probably getting a zero and letter O confused.

Comment: @jdweng I need help to find coordinates of particular keyword on an image such as if you paste keyword it will find the x-y coordinates of that particular word

Comment: [Tesseract - NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Tesseract) -- [Tesseract - GitHub](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract/). Under Apache 2.0 licence.

Comment: @Jimi can you please help me out what exactly this solution is trying to do it would be good if you can provide some code snippet for reference